# Caveats with logistic regression for an expected utility computation?

Tags: regression, logistic, expected-value, games

Suppose we are modeling the probability of heads on a biased coin. We use observable features, for example, its shape and color. We train a logistic regression classifier on a bunch of known coins with known probability distributions and use it to predict the probability $p$ a new coin would come out heads.

An adversary now presents us with a pay-off matrix depending on the coin landing heads or tails. If we knew the true probability, we could compute the expected pay-off and play if that is positive. $p$, however, is only an estimate. What is our best strategy?

In particular, should we bias the predicted probability somehow to account for the shape of the regression error in logistic regression?